# Unable to save new network in metamask wallet

Tags: metamask, ganache

So i took a mnemonic from the ganache. I imported it in the metamask wallet. And
now when i am trying to create a custom rpc network where name would be GANACHE and rpc url  http://localhost:9545 I am unable to save it. The save button is greyed out. How do i enable that?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to fill the chain id to add a new network. As far as I know, the default Chain ID for Ganache is `1337`.

Comment: It says that This Chain ID is currently used by the Localhost 8545 network.

Comment: Are you sure that your RPC URL should be `http://localhost:9545` and not `http://localhost:8545`?

Answer (score 0):

Metamask comes with a default network for localhost using same Chain Id that ganache.

[image]

Just remove it or edit it.